# Row movement for MySQL partitionned tables

Tags: mysql

I am currently considering partitionning tables on my company's application and i was unable to find anywhere in the documentation anything about row movement .

How does MySQL partitionned tables handle updates on records that would move the record from one partition to another?

Exemple :
table1 is a MYISAM table partitionned on the value of col1 which is an integer value.

The value of col1 for each record of table one will increase from 0 to 6 at different point of the time through UPDATE queries.
What happends when a record is updated to have its col1 value change from 0 to 1 ?
Does it trigger an error? Does MySQL delete the record from p0 and inserts a new one into p1 ?

Thanks!

Comment: show some data sample/sql code; as that would be most helpful to us as well as to you =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, but I think it is not a good use-case for partitioning.

I would look at that as at including your `col1` as the first column in a clustered primary key (as in InnoDB). Frequent updating of the rows as itself would not cause an error, but would cause rapid data fragmentation.

Comment: Ok thanks, i'm going to use another column, that is not updated as a partition key. Ofc i'm going to make sure this specific partitionning makes sense and will let me prune efficiently.